# Javascript event target value shows previous value of input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a grid with multiple rows of input textboxes. I am trying to dynamically compute/show the current position and remaining character count for each row textbox (each can be 100 chars max)

```
$("#mygrid tbody").on('focusin', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {                
        let currentPosition = e.target.value.length === 0 ? 1 : e.target.value.length + 1;
        let remainingCharacters = 100 - e.target.value.length;
    }
});

$("#mygrid tbody").on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input') {       
        console.log("e.target.selectionStart : " + e.target.selectionStart);
        console.log("e.target.value : " + e.target.value);
        let currentPosition = e.target.selectionStart + 1;
        let remainingCharacters = 100 - e.target.value.length;      
    }
});
```

What I am seeing is that there is a delay by 1 key shown by the console log statements
i.e. as user types key-by-key "123", what gets logged is below;

```
e.target.selectionStart : 2
e.target.value : 12
```

I am confused why that might be happening ?

Answer (score 5):

To answer the specific question

> event shows previous value of input box
>
> I am confused why that might be happening

What is happening is: when a user presses a key the `keydown` event fires *before* the input has been updated - this allows you to cancel that key if it's not desired in your input.

If you had used `keyup` it would have fired after the input had been updated and your `remainingCharacters` code would have worked as expected.

As already suggested in another answer, using `input` is a good catchall and suitable for your scenario (so code not repeated here).

I wanted to explain *why* this was happening which was missing from the other solution.

Comment: Awesome...Thanks a lot for the explanation...yes, I am planning to use "input" as that seems to be more comprehensive...

Answer (score 2):

Have a go with this. It makes more sense to use input than keydown/keypress etc

```js
$("#mygrid tbody input").on('input focus', function(e) {
  const val = this.value;
  let remainingCharacters = 100 - val.length;
  if (remainingCharacters <= 0) {
    remainingCharacters = 0;
    this.value = val.slice(0, 100)
  }
  $(this).next().val(0).toggleClass("red", remainingCharacters === 0)
  $(this).next().text(remainingCharacters)

}).trigger("input");
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mygrid">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input /><span>100</span></td>
      <td><input value="This is a test"/><span>100</span></td>
      <td><input /><span>100</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input /><span>100</span></td>
      <td><input /><span>100</span></td>
      <td><input /><span>100</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks...let me just try this...Are you suggesting "input" as it would support focus by both mouse & keyboard ?

Comment: Input is any input, paste included. If you want to execute on focus too, just add it to the event handler

Comment: I added focus and counting on load

Comment: I think I'll just keep 'input'.....on('input', function(e) {} as that seems to be working for me (will just try out all combinations with keyboard/mouse including paste)

Comment: See my update. I added focus and I triggered the script onload in case there were already data in the field

Comment: Just a quick followup question....What I observed is that if I move around the text box using left/right arrow keys, the event handler is not getting triggered (i.e. I do not see the correct position displayed when using left/right arrow keys)

Comment: So any reason it does not trigger the event handler in case of left/right arrow keys; 

$("#mygrid tbody input").on('input focus', function(e) {.....})